# Is it possible to write an ActionFilter for .Net Framework and one .Net Core in Single project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am writing a library for code needed in multiple projects and solutions in C#.
I am writing an ActionFilter validating file extensions on File Upload. I need this both in a .Net Framework MVC project and a .Net Core mvc project.

Is it possible to create on shared, .net Standard i.e., project that has two ActionFilters, one for .Net Framework and one for .Net Core?

Answer (score 4):

To get started it helps, in `*.csproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net452;netstandard2.0;</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <DefineConstants>NETCORE;NETSTANDARD;NETSTANDARD2_0</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'">
    <DefineConstants>NET45;NETFULL</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'">
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And for filter class:

```
#if NETCORE
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
#else
using System.Web.Mvc;
#endif

namespace SharedFilter
{
    public class MyFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I've written a library for `Serilog` to enrich logs which targets multiple frameworks. Take a look at the `*.csproj` and classes for more detail.

https://github.com/mo-esmp/serilog-enrichers-clientinfo/blob/master/src/Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo/Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo.csproj